# Store PowerShell script output to a file

Tags: powershell

I have created a script to collect list of users part of remote servers localadmin group and I can see the output in PowerShell prompt.

But how can I save the output to a file?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
foreach ($Computer in Get-Content C:\server.txt)
{
    echo "$Computer"
    $admins = Invoke-Command {net localgroup administrators} -ComputerName $Computer
    $results = $computer + "  " + $admins | Out-File -Append c:\AdminMember.txt
}
```

Comment: The code you posted should only output the computer names to the console. The output of `net localgroup administrators` should be in the file "C:\AdminMember.txt". Please provide evidence ([edit] your question to do so).

Comment: you said correct. I want all the info to be collected on AdminMember.txt, but the output come is not a good format , like this ::-                                                                         servername Alias name administrators Comment Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain Members ------------------------------------------------------------‌​------------------- Administrator group1 group2 user1 user 2The command completed successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to something like this if you want to avoid mangled lines:

```
foreach ($Computer in Get-Content C:\server.txt) {
    $admins = Invoke-Command { net localgroup administrators | Out-String } -Computer $Computer
    "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $computer, $admins | Add-Content 'C:\AdminMember.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply when invoking script in powershell add "> filename" at the end and all shell output will be piped to that file.
Example:

```
commandrunning > output.txt
```

If you want to do it from script you can also do one of the following:

```
$text = 'Hello World'

# Create file:

$text | Set-Content 'file.txt'
#or
$text | Out-File 'file.txt'
#or
$text > 'file.txt'

# Append to file:

$text | Add-Content 'file.txt'
#or
$text | Out-File 'file.txt' -Append
#or
$text >> 'file.txt'
```

Comment: I tried that , But the server name is not coming there against each output

Comment: I want server name against each data, so that I know in which all servers admin group who all are members.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I have done a small change in my script, now I am getting data. But the format is like below                                                                                                                        
    servername  Alias name     administrators Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain  Members  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Administrator group1 group2 user1 user 2The command completed successfully.